# How to get elements in List

Tags: java, algorithm

```
    List<Student> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    Student s = new Student();
    s.setId(1);
    s.setName("A");
    s.setPrice(300);
    Student s1 = new Student();
    s1.setId(2);
    s1.setName("B");
    s1.setPrice(200);
    Student s2 = new Student();
    s2.setId(3);
    s2.setName("C");
    s2.setPrice(200);
    Student s3 = new Student();
    s3.setId(4);
    s3.setName("D");
    s3.setPrice(200);
    Student s4 = new Student();
    s4.setId(4);
    s4.setName("E");
    s4.setPrice(100);
    students.add(s);
    students.add(s1);
    students.add(s2);
    students.add(s3);
    students.add(s4);
```

Normally, I would want to print the top 2 elements like in the code below:

```
List<Student> list = students.stream().limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList()); // ok
```

But I want to check after top 2 ( index 0 and 1 of list student) if price of element ( index 1 ) = element ( n + ... ) printf top 2 + element 3 ,4 ...?

Comment: Please explain better what is the expected result that you need.

Comment: result expect is : 
-case normally
[Student{id=1, name='A', price=300, id = 2, name='B' , price =200 }]
- if student name C or D ... have price = end element top 2 ( B is here ) result : top 2 + C + D

Comment: Please elaborate on the requirements. As it stands now, it is nearly impossible to understand what you want.

Comment: sorry people, i newbie. english of me not good  
requirements : 
-Get top 2 of list student . Result expect Student A , B // I worked
- If end element of list top 2 (Student B ) have price = element after ( Student C and D ) is get continue. Result expect : Student A B C D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an `IntStream` from the indexes of the students `List` and use `filter` to get all elements that have an index less than 2 or those that have the same price as the preceding element.

```
final List<Student> result = IntStream.range(0, students.size())
        .filter(i -> i < 2 || students.get(i).getPrice() == students.get(i - 1).getPrice())
        .mapToObj(students::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

[Demo!](https://ideone.com/NQcOPA)

Comment: Wow. This is work. But i doing / implement styles code other. I will feedback with my code. Many thanks !

Comment: @NguyễnAnhQuân No problem. If you have issues using it, feel free to ask me.

Comment: yes. i'm have issue. 
with data test other
expect result is false. i doing fix

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: i change price of Student B is 100 instead 200. expect result false. i think list student need sort ( i recommend sort desc and i doing )

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Student> sortedList = students.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(Student::getPrice).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    for (int i = 0; i < sortedList.size(); i++) {
        if (i < 2 || sortedList.get(i).getPrice() == sortedList.get(i-1).getPrice()) {
            res.add(sortedList.get(i));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

This picture is my code and worked. Thanks @hev1, all !

Answer (score 0):

So if I got this right, you need to select those students that have price in the top 2.
First, let's find the lower price:

```
Optional<Integer> optMinPrice = students.stream()
    .map(Student::getPrice)
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .distinct()
    .skip(1)
    .findFirst();

int minPrice = optMinPrice.orElse(students.get(0).getPrice());
```

Now, you can select those students with "price" greater or equal to this value:

```
List<Student> list = students.stream()
    .filter(s -> s.getPrice() >= minPrice)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: ``` First, let's find the lower price``` this is key of solutions. Many thanks .